# How to install SDL package using conan? How to find and install packages in conan?

Tags: conan

I would like to start using Conan package manager and I have read the official doc http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/index.html .
I have followed the example and I was able to use poco library as described in the doc.

Now I would like to use SDL library and I found some packages on https://bintray.com/conan/conan-transit for example SDL2/2.0.5@dotfloat/stable.

I tried to install it in two ways:
1. By adding package info to conanfile.txt:

`[requires]
SDL2/2.0.5@dotfloat/stable
[generators]
cmake`

2. With the command, which returns error:

`ERROR: Unable to load conanfile in /root/.conan/data/SDL2/2.0.5/dotfloat/stable/export/conanfile.py
  File "/root/.conan/data/SDL2/2.0.5/dotfloat/stable/export/conanfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    from conans import CMake, ConfigureEnvironment
ImportError: cannot import name ConfigureEnvironment`

Could anyone maybe explain how should I find a package and install it if I'm doing it wrong? Or are the packages broken?

Comment: The packages you are using from conan-transit are mostly deprecated. They are a copy of the old repository that was hosted in conan.io, which moved to bintray (as read-only). But latest conan versions, in preparation for conan 1.0 have removed some things longly deprecated, and ConfigureEnvironment is one of them. So that SDL recipe has to be updated, and will soon. In the meantime you want to check the packages that the bincrafters community are doing: https://bincrafters.github.io/ Repo: https://bintray.com/bincrafters

Comment: @drodri That is actually very helpful. Thank you very much.